# Linq to sql/C# - multiple where search off key/value pairs

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm new to Linq to Sql and am trying to do the following in C#.

I have a table that's a key/value store (that also has an fk to a user).  I want to do a search off the key names and values as an or.  On the front end, I allow them to add "filters" that are key names, then they can search for a value.  So they can search N items, where N is the number of filters.

In plain sql, where N=3, it'd look like the following.  datakey and datavalue are columns in the table (varchar(255)).

```
SELECT * from table
 where (datakey='option1' and datavalue='value1')
    or (datakey='option2' and datavalue='value2')
    or (datakey='option3' and datavalue='value3')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a technology called DynamicQuery which would allow you to build up LINQ expressions via a string, which you may find helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as [jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472232/jasper) said you can use the **[Dynamic LINQ Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)** to accomplish what you want.

**Here is a quick and dirty example** (note: I have not tested this *exact*
 code):

```
List<string> options = new List<string>();
List<string> values = new List<string>();

options.Add("option1");
values.Add("value1");
options.Add("option2");
values.Add("value2");

StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < options.Count; i++)
{
    if (queryString.Length > 0)
        queryString.Append(" Or ");

    queryString.Append(string.Format("(datakey = \"{0}\" And dataValue = \"{1}\")", options[i], values[i]));
}

var query = context.YourTable.Where(queryString.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you. I gave credit to Jasper, but the sample was a huge help.  I was trying this right before I left work Friday, but ran into some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use C#'s equivalent operators, `&&` and `||`:

```
from t in context.table
where (t.datakey == "option1" && datavalue == "value1")
   || (t.datakey == "option2" && datavalue == "value2")
   || (t.datakey == "option3" && datavalue == "value3")
select t
```

Comment: um, wont that query reduce the result set rather than expanding it? i think you should be using union there

Comment: @jasper: Yes, shame on me; that's the second time in a couple of months that I've made exactly the same mistake. Concatenating `||` arbitrarily is actually much harder than `&&` (and better done using an expression builder class, who's name escapes me just now). I've removed that part of the answer.

Comment: i think you were on the right track with your last answer, do the loop through all the expressions, and use union to add all the results together, and filter for duplicates

Comment: @jasper: Yes, that option came up the last time, too. The problem I had with it is that it doesn't produce the same SQL. It is, of course, a perfectly valid answer (pending performance tests).

Comment: Thanks, but N is variable based on the responses from the user, so my issue was I wasn't sure how to build it in a loop or such.  I'm using these now in other places no problem.